# Database query not working for Heroku deployment of Django/Python Project

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am deploying a Django project on Heroku. The deployment is successful and most functions of my web app are running just fine. However, I am having an issue with a single database query that seems not to work correctly on Heroku but works just fine on localhost.

I am using this url_pattern:

```
path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
```

Then in my views, I am running this queryset filter in my CategoryView:

```
def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_articles = Article.objects.filter(category=cats.replace('-', ' '))
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'cats': cats.title().replace('-', ' '), 
    'category_articles': category_articles})
```

I don't have a Category Model. Instead, I am using forms.py to run category choices as follows:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Politics', 'Politics'),
    ('Business', 'Business'),
    ('Updates', 'Updates'),
    ('Education', 'Education'),
)

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('article_image', 'author', 'title', 'category', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'article_image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control',}),
```

The following is my Article Model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

The html form has the select option for the choices provided. Once selected, an option is stored in the database when the user submits the form.

From the url_pattern and my CategoryView, I am trying to query the database and display objects in the order of categories. Unfortunately, this works just perfectly fine on my localhost, but returns no object in Heroku. I used MySQL during development, which I set up using XAMPP. However, in Heroku, I used Postgresql.

What could be the problem? I have seen videos people using sqlite during development and deploy the project to Heroku and causes no problem.

Comment: Can you share a sample data? What result do you get if you print all articles?

Comment: When I print all articles they work just fine. The articles display correctly on the homepage with another queryset. When I run the following, it displays correctly: articles_list = Article.objects.all()

Comment: Then most likely there's something wrong with the filter you use. Can you show some sample Articles with their Category, and the string you pass on your url?

Comment: The filter works in localhost. For example, localhost:8000/category/politics displays all articles under the politics category. However, on app-name.herokuapp.com/category/politics no article is displayed.